# State is undefined, when I setState() inside component did mount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, jsx

I am new to react and unable to set state after fetching data from firebase in component did mount function ,keeps getting error contact is not defined inside the component did mount.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        contacts: [
            { name: 'sachin', number: '445343' },
            { name: 'nihil', number: '33335555' },
            { name: 'chicken', number: '434355' },
        ]
    }
    this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this);
}


componentDidMount = () => {

        let currentComponent = this;
        fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
            if (user) {
                console.log(user.uid)
                var uid = user.uid;
                db.collection(uid)
                    .get()
                    .then((querySnapshot) => {
                        const contacts = querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                            const data = doc.data()
                            contacts.push(data)
                        })
                        console.log(contacts)
                        this.setState({contacts});
                    });

            } else {
                // No user is signed in.
            }

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should not bind `componentDidMount` method in `constructor`

And second, you are pushing in `contacts` before initializing it. So Try something like below:-

```
componentDidMount() {
        fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            if (user) {
                console.log(user.uid)
                var uid = user.uid;
                db.collection(uid)
                    .get()
                    .then((querySnapshot) => {
                        const contacts = [];  // initialize contants here
                        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                            contacts.push(doc.data())
                        })
                        console.log(contacts)
                        this.setState({contacts});
                    });

            } else {
                // No user is signed in.
            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: still getting cannot read property setState of undefined

Comment: Are you calling `componentDidMount` from anywhere? Did you convert `componentDidMount` from arrow function to normal function? Did you remove bind this to `componentDidMount`  from constructor?

Comment: i removed the bind and put the calling inside another getdata() function and put it inside componeneDidMount ,and binded that getdata() function.

Comment: I don't understand why do you need to call `componentDidMount` from other function? `componentDidMount` will be called with current component mounts first time.

Comment: bro one thing worked,by removing thi ```fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
            if (user) {
                console.log(user.uid)
                var uid = user.uid;```` putting only the db.collection .get it is working fine ,can you tell me a way to get the user uid globally.

Comment: Okay I have updated my answer. Can you please try again?

Comment: bro it worked i put the get user id function inside the componentDidMount and then called another getData function

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        contacts: [
            { name: 'sachin', number: '445343' },
            { name: 'nihil', number: '33335555' },
            { name: 'chicken', number: '434355' },
        ]
    }
    this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this);
}


componentDidMount = () => {

        let currentComponent = this;
        fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
            if (user) {
                console.log(user.uid)
                var uid = user.uid;
                db.collection(uid)
                    .get()
                    .then((querySnapshot) => {
                        const contacts = [];
                        querySnapshot.map(item => contacts .push(item.data));
                        this.setState({contacts});
                    });

            } else {
                // No user is signed in.
            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: its saying querySnapshot.map is not valid

Comment: are you sure this "querySnapshot" is an array ?

Answer (score 0):

````
   

 componentDidMount() {
    var user = fire.auth().currentUser;

    if (user) {
        console.log(user.uid)
        var uid = user.uid;
    } else {
    // No user is signed in.
    }
    console.log('comp: ' + uid)
    this.getData(uid);
}                                                                                     
 getData = (e) => {

           db.collection(e)
                .get()
                .then((querySnapshot) => {
                    const contacts = [];  // initialize contants here
                    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                        contacts.push(doc.data())
                    })
                    console.log(contacts)
                    this.setState({contacts});
                });

}     ```  this worked I think putting the fire.auth().currentuser inside getData function did not let it set the state .
````